# gettext alias and zend framework 3 not working

Tags: php, translate, zend-framework3

i am working with zend framework 3
the problem is that from the view with

echo $this->translate('About');

is working but on the code with _('Home') is not working 
on podedit appears the 'Home' but on the site is not translating 
and i have no errors

please help.

thanks

```
 $items[] = [
            'id' => 'home',
            'label' => _('Home'),
            'link'  => $url('home')
        ];
```

Comment: $this->traduz();
    
        $url = $this->urlHelper;
        $traduzir=$this->translator;
        
        $items = [];
        
        $items[] = [
            'id' => 'home',
            'label' => $traduzir->translate('Home'),
            'link'  => $url('home')
        ];

Answer (score 0):

it is working now

'label' => $traduzir->translate('Home'),

---

```
$this->traduz();

        $url = $this->urlHelper;
        $traduzir=$this->translator;

        $items = [];

        $items[] = [
            'id' => 'home',
            'label' => $traduzir->translate('Home'),
            'link'  => $url('home')
        ];
```